# MYSQL UPDATE with LIMIT and ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, limit

so I was reading about UPDATE with LIMIT and how it doesnt really return what you want.

Ive been running this statement, and it seems to be working.  But Im worried when my dataset grows, and I go into production if this query will stop working.

Could anyone tell me what is a better way to select a certain batch, and update.

I've read a lot about that it only works if you sort by ID.  But in my case I want to order by Assign_count.

Here's my query...

```
UPDATE leads SET assign_date='".date('Y-m-d')."',status='ASSIGNED' 
   WHERE city='".$city."' AND status='NEW' 
   ORDER BY assign_count ASC LIMIT 40");
```

I'm ordering by the assign_count, and limiting it to 40.  Will this actually select the leads I want to be selecting??  Just curious.  After reading all about UPDATE with LIMIT.  I'm kinda scared that it won't select what I want.  Even though it seems to be working right now on a little bit of data.

Comment: What your problem? Your query looking fine

Comment: @ThinkkSo  thats exactly what I want.  So is this query fine then?  Can I leave it as is??  The answer below mentions something about row count only.  Which I keep reading about...Im just not too sure.

Comment: @KyleK what is the type of your mysql engine

Comment: @KyleK actually now that i remember you have to use `row count` so your code wont break

Comment: this is what you need `UPDATE leads SET assign_date='".date('Y-m-d')."',status='ASSIGNED' WHERE city='".$city."' AND status='NEW' ORDER BY assign_count ASC LIMIT 0,40`

Comment: Are you sure?? Why is it working fine how it is??  What exactly does the 0, do?  Sorry for the newb questions

Comment: it starts from the index 0 to 40 and if it was 10 40 it will skip the first 10 and start at 11 to 40

Comment: so would 40 without the 0 work?? Cuz it seems to work right now.  Just wondering if it is better to make it 0,40 or just leave it as LIMIT 40

Comment: well i would advice you to do 0, 40 for better practice but you can also go your way and do LIMIT 40 if it still works

Answer (score 0):

```
   UPDATE leads SET assign_date='".date('Y-m-d')."',status='ASSIGNED' WHERE city='".$city."' AND status='NEW' ORDER BY assign_count ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

`LIMIT` can be used with `UPDATE` but with the `row count` only